# Word for 'free' loan

Tags: word-request

My sister runs a charity organization that produces wigs for women who have lost their hair due to cancer treatment.

We are working on a website for her organization and I am looking for a word that implies 'free loan'.

Her charity lends wigs to women in a formal way - borrowers need to fill out an application and, if accepted, sign a legally binding contract outlining borrower's obligations, such as returning the wig when their contract is due, keeping it in mint condition, etc. However it's all free - they won't pay a cent for it (unless they damage the wig).

Whenever someone says 'loan', I always think of a 'bank loan' or something of the sort.

What do you call a formal-but-free loan?

Comment: ***no-charge lending [of wigs]***. You don't want loans here: lending is the word.  to lend wigs to women free of charge. ***free-of-charge wig lending***.

Comment: How about **"free rental of wigs"**? But I suggest a returnable deposit to cover loss or damage.

Comment: @Weather Vane It isn't a rental. A rental means you pay. Car rental, house rental=you pay for  those.

Comment: You could call it **Wiglets**, which is neat, sounds like a pun on twiglets and suggests borrowing.

Comment: Whether the process attracts interest or other charges doesn't really change the fact that it's a ***loan***. OP's context is an unusual one, but essentially the same thing happens in relation to books managed by public ("lending") libraries. In which context it's perfectly natural to say, for example, *That book on the coffee table isn't actually mine. It's on loan from the library.* I don't hear people saying *You can borrow a copy from the library,* though. *You can **get it at / take it out from** the library* seem more natural to me.

Comment: While the technical meaning of 'lend' vs 'loan' is pretty much identical, in my experience 'loan' has a much stronger financial connotation. Generally speaking, Libraries 'lend' books, whereas a Bank 'loans' money, but both examples are commonly reversed.

Answer (score 1):

**Lend** is a good term that might *suggest* an interest-free loan.

> verb (past and past participle lent) *[with object]*
>
> grant to (someone) the use of (something) on the understanding that it shall be returned: Stewart asked me to lend him my car | the pictures were lent to each museum in turn.
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lend)</sub>

Comment: Of course, one can "lend at x% interest".